# C# -- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
int p = 0;
int q = 0;
p = 0;
q = 0;

string username = null;
username = Session["user"];
int total = 0;
for (total = 1; total <= 120; total++) {
    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
    ch = Page.FindControl("C" + total);

    if (ch.Checked == true & ch.Enabled == true) {
        string query = "insert into order_master values('" + username + "','" + drpselectmovie.SelectedValue + "','" + drpselectdate.SelectedValue + "','" + drpselectshow.SelectedValue + "'," + drpselectclass.SelectedValue + ",'" + ch.ID + "'," + drpselectclass.SelectedValue + ")";
        SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ch.Enabled = false;
        if (total <= 72) {
            p = p + 1;
        } else {
            q = q + 1;

        }

    }
}
int price = 0;
price = p * 180 + q * 120;
txtprice.Text = price.ToString;
Session.Add("tickettotal", txtprice.Text);
cn.Close();
```

Total is a variable the number of the checkbox to determine what checbox have been checked. On its design or in the .aspx code I change all the checkboxes ID to C1,C2,C3 and so on. That's why "C" + total is needed to find so that it will be equal to its ID. However, I'm having an error in ch = Page.FindControl("C" + total). Is anyone knows how to fix this? Is it error in declaration? or Is it there something I forgot to add in the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you try to set parent class (`System.Web.UI.Control`) as child class (`System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox`):

```
ch = Page.FindControl("C" + total);
```

Use keyword `as` to assign it correctly:

```
ch = Page.FindControl("C" + total) as CheckBox;
```

Note that you may get `null` if the `System.Web.UI.Control` is not of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox`.

Comment: I tried this one but now I'm having an error of ***The type or namespace name 'WebControls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*** even though I do have 'using System.Web.UI.WebControls;' at the top of my file.

Comment: @user808317 if you have already have `using System.Web.UI.WebControls` then you don't need that. Simply use `as CheckBox`, that being said, be more careful about `Find` because if there is any other `Control` with the name starting with `C` and not `CheckBox` you would get `null` exception if you don't filter that out/handling `null` `ch`

Comment: @user808317 are you using `WebForms` here?

Comment: IT'S OKAY NOW! :))) ***THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP***

Comment: @user808317 great... :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks odd to declare  "CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();" inside of the for loop. Try declaring it before the for loop. I might be wrong...